# Call a function from a function pointer without assigning?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Normally we have to do like this to invoke a function from a function pointer:

```
int foo()
{
}

int main()
{
    int (*pFoo)() = foo; // pFoo points to function foo()
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In the Linux kernel code, [sched_class](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/include/linux/sched.h#L1101) has many function pointers:

```
struct sched_class {
        const struct sched_class *next;

        void (*enqueue_task) (struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int flags);
        void (*dequeue_task) (struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, int flags);
        void (*yield_task) (struct rq *rq);
        bool (*yield_to_task) (struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p, bool preempt);
        .....
}
```

In [pick_next_task](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/kernel/sched/core.c#L3122) function, it defines a local instance of `sched_class` named `class`, and directly invoke the function in it without assigning to external functions with the same signature (start from `for_each_class`):

```
static inline struct task_struct *
pick_next_task(struct rq *rq)
{
        const struct sched_class *class;
        struct task_struct *p;
    /*
     * Optimization: we know that if all tasks are in
     * the fair class we can call that function directly:
     */
    if (likely(rq->nr_running == rq->cfs.h_nr_running)) {
            p = fair_sched_class.pick_next_task(rq);
            if (likely(p))
                    return p;
    }

    for_each_class(class) {
            p = class->pick_next_task(rq);
            if (p)
                    return p;
    }

    BUG(); /* the idle class will always have a runnable task */
}
```

Is this because each function pointer in the `sched_class` has the same name as the actual implemented function, so every time a call is made via a function pointer of `sched_class`, it will automatically find the matching symbol in the kernel address space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `for_each_class` should clear it up for you

```
 #define for_each_class(class) \
       for (class = sched_class_highest; class; class = class->next)
```

If you go on tracing, `sched_class_highest` wil end up something like this

```
#define sched_class_highest (&stop_sched_class)
extern const struct sched_class stop_sched_class;

/*
* Simple, special scheduling class for the per-CPU stop tasks:
*/
const struct sched_class stop_sched_class = {
      .next                   = &rt_sched_class,

      .enqueue_task           = enqueue_task_stop,
      .dequeue_task           = dequeue_task_stop,
      .yield_task             = yield_task_stop,

      .check_preempt_curr     = check_preempt_curr_stop,

      .pick_next_task         = pick_next_task_stop,
      .put_prev_task          = put_prev_task_stop,

#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
      .select_task_rq         = select_task_rq_stop,
#endif

     .set_curr_task          = set_curr_task_stop,
     .task_tick              = task_tick_stop,

     .get_rr_interval        = get_rr_interval_stop,

     .prio_changed           = prio_changed_stop,
     .switched_to            = switched_to_stop,
};
```

Now are you happy? :)

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.3/kernel/sched/sched.h#L850

Look at the expansion of `for_each_class` macro. It assigns values to the `class` pointer before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Each `sched_class` structure, and the function pointers it contains, is initialized (otherwise, it's probably a bug). For instance, the fair scheduling [class](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/kernel/sched/fair.c#L216) is initialized in `kernel/sched/fair.c` (see [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/kernel/sched/fair.c#L5563)):

```
const struct sched_class fair_sched_class = {
        .next                   = &idle_sched_class,
        /* lots of assignments */
        .pick_next_task         = pick_next_task_fair,
        /* etc. */
};
```